# installing Nvidia NVS 3100M driver fails, what am I missing?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

running Kubuntu 14.04 in Oracle virtual box 5.0 on Dell (Windows 7) E6410 laptop.

I've installed DKMS & guest additions. I can get better resolution now.

But I assume for performance I need to install the Nvidia driver.

I downloaded it from here:

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/77525/en-us

and I can run it with:

sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.32.run

but I get two errors.

1. it seems to think I don't have an Nvidia GPU, which I've confirmed several times. What's up? is VB preventing it from seeing the GPU?
2. Also an error about running an X server, but I saw a response here that it should not be an issue...

Comment: I found a way to shut down the X server on ask-ubuntu, but now I'm totally screwed. No apps, no way to run a Konsole session, nothing! I'll probably have to reinstall Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT install video drivers to systems running in VirtualBox.

Guest systems do not have direct access to hardware.

Install the Guest Additions instead.

Comment: Awesome, I had no idea! That saves me a lot of time and energy. So is the performance significantly reduced? I could do a native Kubuntu install instead of the virtual box flavor.

Comment: VB install is significantly slower. Guest system does not use all CPUs and not more than half of RAM.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that as well since I have a spare hard disk.